# Adding SearchBar to CollectionView

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I've created a CollectionView (as a CollectionViewController in IB) and it occurred to me that I should have a search function.

I want to add a SearchBar above my CollectionView in Storyboard, however it physically will not allow me and keeps sliding below which obviously won't work.

Is there a way to get around this, or do I need to rebuild my CollectionViewController from scratch with SearchBar at the top?

Can I add the SearchBar programmatically to the existing CollectionViewController?
See picture for reference:

[image]

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a search bar above a UICollectionView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355653/how-can-i-add-a-search-bar-above-a-uicollectionview)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to copy your collectionview to UIViewController & setting it to be delegate & datasource.
This way will allow you to add a searchbar above collectionview.

you can further detect searchbar text change & apply changes to collection view data.