# How can I add a search bar above a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I would like to allow users of my app to search for images using a `UISearchBar` above a `UICollectionView`. According to my understanding, a `UICollectionView` must be in a `UICollectionViewController` to work properly. However, Xcode won't let me put a search bar in a `UICollectionViewController`. I also can't use a generic `UIViewController` as the collection view won't work properly. How can I achieve the functionality that I want?

Comment: find the below link, this may help you.

[example-how-to-integrate-uicollectionview-with-uisearchbar -1](https://maniacdev.com/2015/01/example-how-to-integrate-uicollectionview-with-uisearchbar)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**CollectionView + SearchBar** with **Swift3 + Storyboard** implementation.

**Creating the Header View:**

[image: Creating the Header View]

**Creating the Search Bar:**

[image: Creating the Search Bar]

**Create the reusable view custom class**

[image: Create the reusable view custom class]

**Set the reusable view custom class**

[image: Set the reusable view custom class]

**Create the search bar outlet**

[image: Create the search bar outlet in custom class]

**Trick: Connect the search bar delegate to COLLECTION VIEW class, the search bar outlet goes to the CUSTOM REUSABLE VIEW CLASS**

[image: Connect the search bar delegate to collection view class]

**Implement the CollectionView header method of protocol**

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

         if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
             let headerView:UICollectionReusableView =  collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewHeader", for: indexPath)

             return headerView
         }

         return UICollectionReusableView()

    }
```

**Set the Searchbar delegate**

```
    class MyCollectionViewController: (other delegates...), UISearchBarDelegate {
```

**And finally, your the search bar delegate methods will be called in your CollectionView Class**

```
//MARK: - SEARCH

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if(!(searchBar.text?.isEmpty)!){
        //reload your data source if necessary
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if(searchText.isEmpty){
        //reload your data source if necessary
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach has a few side-effects; search bar will appear in every section header, search bar will scroll out of view, and search bar will loose its firstResponder status when self.collectionView?.reloadData() is called. Check out Jeremiah-de great step by step repo for using UISearchController with UICollectionView https://github.com/jeremiah-de/CollectionViewSearch/tree/basic-collection-view

Comment: @mourodrigo Hey, when I'm trying to override that collectionView method (viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind), xCode throws an error "method does not override any method from its super class". I did add the searchbar delegate to my viewController and that outlet, I've set UISearchBarDelegate to my viewController too... One problem when running the code is that the search bar isn't rendered, there is the header space but no searchBar inside

Comment: @Manu , the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind does not need the "override" on the method signature implementation. I guess this may fix your issue. If you need anything else just ping me on my inbox. =)

Comment: Very nicely explained and with pictures, thank you for your effort, 
+1

Comment: A full blown tutorial inside SO. – The future is now –

Answer (score 2):

It is not mandatory to have `UICollectionView` inside `UICollectionViewController`. `UICollectionView` is just like `UITableView` and can be added anywhere. All you need to do is implement `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocols. You can follow following tutorial [Supplementary Header](http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/) and add search bar as a supplementary header of `UICollectionView`.

Comment: I did that but I was getting NSExceptions even though I implemented UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource

Comment: What was the Exception?